# Could there be electricity in an ocean city?

Tags: electricity, water

I was wondering if a "mermaid city" (where people lived in the ocean and somehow breathed underwater) could have any means to create or use electricity. Thanks!

Comment: Sure.  Waves and currents can be harnessed to generate electricity.

Comment: Would [worldbuilding.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: Nuclear submarines generate electricity.

Comment: Using electricity under water? Not a problem. _Discovering_ electricity? That's a whole different ball of wax. People only discovered electricity by observing the effects of electric charges that were trapped on insulating surfaces by the [_triboelectric effect_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triboelectric_effect). But charges won't be trapped on any surface that is in contact with salt water.

Comment: there are submarines using nuclear reactors, no?

Answer (score 5):

It is feasible - but would be a lot harder than it was for us.

**Conductors** - It wouldn't be an easy task for mer-people to smelt copper or other suitable conductors underwater. High temperatures under water are difficult to achieve. A possible solution would be to use metals that can be found in the environment - so maybe gold wiring?

**Insulation** - A major issue is that the oceans conduct electricity pretty effectively. So *all* circuit elements would need to be well insulated. Bare wires; open sockets; a 'bread-board' of components sitting on a table; a battery stored on an underwater bench - none of the above would be practical. Possible solutions might be insulating everything, or working in 'vacuum vessels'. In principle it might be possible to replace the sea water in a room with pure distilled water (which has much lower conductivity).

**Generation** - Something like a lead-acid battery would be feasible (assuming the mer-people can also solve the problems with doing wet chemistry underwater). Hydro-power is obviously impractical, as would be generators powered by fuel-burning motors. Geothermal generation from deep undersea vents might be practical; similarly nuclear power. But any generator would be complicated by the much higher frictional losses when operated in water - so generators and other rotating machinery would be best operated under vacuum.

**Reticulation** - Probably no specific issue here so long as the insulation problem had been solved. But plug/socket arrangements would need to be clever in order to allow connection/disconnection without producing short circuits in the surrounding water.

**Safety** - Hideously unsafe unless limited to low voltages.

Comment: Re: fuel-based motors, there are a number substances that burn underwater because they contain their own oxidizers (including some explosives). The most famous example here is thermite, though this may not be suitable for power generation...
Re: reticulation, it seems likely that an underwater civilzation would quickly realize the potential of induction for these purposes. You can "plug" an insulated wire with a coil at the end into an insulated socket with another coil inside, and use this for power transfer.

Comment: Inductive energy transfer may be the best option although if there is a significant volume of salt water in the transfer region it could reduce efficiency.